# C# receives large data from web services?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

what is the enterprise standard way to deal with large data from web services? The language is c# mvc with razor engine. previously, i used angularjs, ui-grid, kendoui. i am wondering what's the standard solution in .net mvc razor engine environment. Thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. What do *Javascript* frameworks have to do with "large data"? What are you trying to do? Processing 100K rows of data to predict stock prices is different from displaying 500 rows in a Kendo UI grid with paging or infinite scrolling

Comment: I'm afraid neither of angularjs, ui-grid, kendoui or even razor is related to web services. Can you be more specific? Is your problem about displaying large data that you obtained from another application, or you want to provide a web service which will return large data?

Comment: I mean what to use in c# mvc to receive & display data from web services. I am making the application to consume data from web services.

Comment: Say the web service returns a json, then what to use in controller to store those json? if i don't do it in view with javascript. is it dataset or what?

Comment: if Server have a paging or/and filtering,  you should use it to accept smaller amounts of data. If server not support filtering and paging (that also sometimes happends due to buisness requirements) - and recieved data is valid for some time - might try to use a caching, and if *all* data rapidly changes and you should allways have latest recodrs - then it would be a chalange

Comment: Let's not worrying about pagination etc. Is dataset a good class to receive & temporarily store those json? or Odata is the way to go if it is enterprise level? Or what are some good alternatives to Odata?

Comment: Why do you even bother to store Json in DataSet, which has a big memory footprint.

Comment: If the data is too large (e.g. larger than 1 MB.) do not store it in a single variable. Use a stream object instead to transfer it from the source to the output. Otherwise you may run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GridMVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/).It has wonderful on-demand pagination with all the generic support for a grid control and incorporate with   [Dynamic Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/)

Other option is [Jquery datatable](https://datatables.net/) but i would prefer the first one

Answer (score -2):

cache it somewhere and have an ascny call for a JSON structure

Comment: This should be a comment. Besides, how do you know eg that the OP wants to display the data or why do you think that "large" actually means "at most a few thousand"? Why store something in an inefficient format like Json if you want to cache it on the server? What if the OP wanted to display just 50 of the eg 2000 rows at a time?

Comment: everything that need more than a second to retrieve is large. He wants data to be loaded into a website. If it's retrieved from the DB than do the JSON load directly. If it's an external service, cache it and than retrieve it through JSON.

Comment: There several options on how to deal with cacheing. DB, file, inmemory, .... you choose. This is the best possible answer to be provided based on the input he provided.

Comment: garbage in, garbage out